# Explanation of "Unchecked cast" warning in Java

Tags: java, exception, casting

im only a beginner and I'd like a good soul to help me ;)I got this method and on the line:

```
( (HashSet<String>) pos[targetPos]).add(word);
```

it gives me an exception

```
    (Unchecked cast from Object to HashSet<String>)
```

I tried to change Object[pos] to String[pos] to be more specific but it then gives me an error on this line: `pos[targetPos] = new HashSet<String>();`

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashSet<String> to String
```

this is the method:

```
public void add(String word, Object[] root){

    Object[] pos = root;
    int wordIndex = 0;
    int targetPos;

    if(word.length()>=3){
        for(int i = 1; i <=3; i++){
            targetPos = word.charAt(wordIndex) -'a'; //convert a letter into index eg a==0
            if(i==3){
                if(pos[targetPos]==null){
                    pos[targetPos] = new HashSet<String>();
                }
                ( (HashSet<String>) pos[targetPos]).add(word);
                //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pos));
                break;

            }//end if outer if
            else{
                if(pos[targetPos]==null){
                    pos[targetPos] = new Object[28];
                }
                wordIndex++;
                pos =  (Object[]) pos[targetPos];
            }
        }//end of for
    }

}
```

The root is

```
 Object[] root = new Object[28];
```

Comment: `"Unchecked cast from Object to HashSet<String>"` sounds like it's a compile-time warning rather than an exception. Can you clarify please?

Comment: You might want to change your title; an unchecked exception means something completely different.

Answer (score 3):

The "unchecked cast" message is a warning. The compiler is warning you that it cannot be sure that the explicit cast from `Object` to `HashSet<String>` can happen safely during runtime, which means that it is possible that if your array of type `Object` contains something *other* than `HashSet<String>`, you will get a `ClassCastException` during runtime when the JVM attempts to cast that object into type `HashSet<String>`. Essentially the compiler is warning you beforehand that you are doing something that is potentially unsafe and it can be a source of problems later.

It is not a good practice to simply use a raw object of arrays. If you are going to be sure that the array is only going to contain `HashSet<String>` objects, then you should probably type it as such (i.e., `Set<String>[]`; use the interface instead of the concrete implementation for your type because then you can switch implementations when you want). The only time you should do an explicit cast is when you can be *absolutely sure* that the object that you are casting is most definitely of the type that you are casting it to. For example, if you have an object that implements an interface, and also assume that you are in some class that is most definitely working with a specific concrete-implementation of that interface. In this case, it is acceptable to cast it from that interface into the concrete type.

Your method should look like this:

```
public void add(String word, Set<String>[] root){

    Set<String>[] pos = root; //You probably don't even need this since you have "root"
    ...
}
```

Also, consider using a `List` of `Set<String>` instead of an array:

```
public void add(String word, List<Set<String>> root){

    List<Set<String>> pos = root; //You probably don't even need this since you have "root"
    ...
}
```

Comment: @user1747976 Check out my updated answer. You should basically use the actual type that you want, i.e., `Set<String>`.

Comment: I did that ((Set<String>) pos[targetPos]).add(word) and it still gives me a warning  Unchecked cast from Object to Set<String>

Comment: @user1747976 No, you shouldn't be casting *at all*. Change the type of the argument of your method to `Set<String>[]` or `List<Set<String>>`.

Comment: I also need to change  pos[targetPos] = new Object[28] into pos[targetPos] = new Set<String>[28] ???  then I have an error:  cannot convert from Set<String>[] to Set<String>

Comment: @user1747976 Are you trying to maintain a collection of `Set<String>`? Basically, are you trying to working with multiple `Set<String>` instances? From what I understand, you basically have an array of `Set<String>`. If that's the case, then you would need `pos[targetPos] = new HashSet<String>();` assuming that `pos` is of type `Set<String>[]`.

Comment: yes I need to maintan a collection of Set<String>. I need to create a set<string> with 28 positions in it

Comment: @user1747976 Do what I described earlier; type the argument as `Set<String>[]`. Individual instances will be typed simply as `Set<String>`.

Comment: I got another error: cannot convert from Set<String> to Set<String>[] on line   pos = pos[targetPos];

Comment: @user1747976 You can't cast an object into an array.

Answer (score 3):

`pos[]` is defined as an `Object` array. When you cast it to `HashSet<String>` later, Java doesn't know that you can do that. That's what an unchecked cast is -- the compiler is warning you that you MIGHT be doing something unsafe.

You can make the warning go away by changing the type of `pos` to `HashSet<String>[]`.

Comment: if I define it as a String array it says cannot convert from HashSet<String> to String

Comment: @user1747976 String array is different from an array of hash-sets of strings

Comment: You don't want a String array, you want an array of HashSet<String>.